# Vue.js framework not working in a simple html page using CDN

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I started studying vue.js recently, I went to study about forms and when I went to open the file with live server it didn't work, so I try to run with xampp, but didn't work to. It had worked before, but this time it didn't work.
Can anyone help me find where I went wrong in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Starting with vuejs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
      <form>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" v-model="name">
        <br>

        <label for="wow">yes or no
          <input type="radio" v-model="news" value="yes" name="wow"> yes
          <input type="radio" v-model="news" value="no" name="wow"> no
        </label>
        <br>

        <label for="sports">sports</label> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sports"v-model="sports" value="futebol"> futball <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sports"v-model="sports" value="f1"> f1 <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sports"v-model="sports" value="run"> run
        <br>

        <label for="">how you meet us</label>
        <select v-model="meet">
          <option value="google">google</option>
          <option value="journal">journal</option>
          <option value="TV">TV</option>
        </select>
        
        <br>
      </form> 
    <hr>
    name: {{name}} <br>
    news: {{news}} <br>
    sports: {{sports}} <br>
    meet : {{meet}} <br>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          name:"",
          new = "",
          sports :"",
          meet : ""
        }
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An issue I can see is a typo in your Vue declaration: `new = "",` should be `news: "",`. No equals assignment in object declarations.

Comment: ^^^ typo problem.  Works (compiles and runs) once that is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is simply a typo. `new = "",` should be `news: ""` in your Vue declaration.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Starting with vuejs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
      <form>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" v-model="name">
        <br>

        <label for="wow">yes or no
          <input type="radio" v-model="news" value="yes" name="wow"> yes
          <input type="radio" v-model="news" value="no" name="wow"> no
        </label>
        <br>

        <label for="sports">sports</label> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sports"v-model="sports" value="futebol"> futball <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sports"v-model="sports" value="f1"> f1 <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sports"v-model="sports" value="run"> run
        <br>

        <label for="">how you meet us</label>
        <select v-model="meet">
          <option value="google">google</option>
          <option value="journal">journal</option>
          <option value="TV">TV</option>
        </select>
        
        <br>
      </form> 
    <hr>
    name: {{name}} <br>
    news: {{news}} <br>
    sports: {{sports}} <br>
    meet : {{meet}} <br>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          name:"",
          news: "", //not `new = "",`
          sports :"",
          meet : ""
        }
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also worth noting that you can "run" this out of the box in your browser as an HTML file, since that's all this is. Vue is just a JS framework and doesn't need any special stack to run.

Comment: woow I rate when this happens always is just one simple thing